Experience Cloud site - Well-Known URIs
I want to create three pages whose URL path will look like this:
siteBase URL + /.well-known/security.txt
siteBase URL + /security.txt
siteBase URL + /pgp-key.txt
Salesforce won't let me use dots in the URL when creating pages in Builder.
As an example of the page I want to create, let it be this one: https://www.youtube.com/.well-known/security.txt

Try via site redirect URL. Haven't tried that with the dot, caveat emptor.
